# Changing legend spacing to be further away from map border in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, scale

I am using QGIS 3.2.3

I am creating a map in which I have added a legend to (see figure below).

[image]

My issue is that I am trying to create a legend which has spacing between the two columns. I have achieved this by `spacing` --> `Column space` within the legend properties within map compose. However the spacing within the columns has resulted in my *items* being pushed to the border of the map and legend.

This has created a large amount of spacing in the center of the legend (indicated by the pink box). I need to find a way of creating the spacing to be closer to the border and the items to move further left. seen in the next figure (where the spacing is shared evenly at the sides and the items move closer inwards).

[image]

I have also tried using the `align button` to move its position and that doesn't work either.

Comment: There is a `Spacing/ Box space` property that may be of some use, but it seems to control the top, bottom, left and right margins all equally.

Answer (score 0):

as Andy wrote it is in spacing "Legend items" --> "Space before items" or "General" for overal space.